# JQuery - enable table row dropdown on checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have a table with checkbox and a dropdown in each row. I'd like the dropdown input fields to be disabled on page load BUT became enabled when checkbox for that particular row is checked.

Can you help me with JQuery code which can do that?

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Box</th><th>No</th><th>No 1</th><th>No 2</th><th>No 3</th><th>No 4</th><th>Chosen</th><th>Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="341"/></td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>13</td><td class='key'><select name="chosen_key">
<option value="1" selected="selected">N</option>
<option value="2">Y</option>
<option value="3">M</option>
<option value="4">A</option>
<option value="5">R</option>
</select></td><td>2011-01-28</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="342"/></td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>10</td><td>23</td><td class='key'><select name="chosen_key">
<option value="1">N</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Y</option>
<option value="3">M</option>
<option value="4">A</option>
<option value="5">R</option>
</select></td><td>2011-01-28</td></tr>
.
.
.
</tbody>

> Blockquote
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Disable select elements
  $('select').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('disabled','true');
  });

  // Enable them on click
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
     var s = $(this).parent('td').siblings('td.key').children('select');

     if(s.is(':disabled')) {
        s.removeAttr('disabled');   
     } else {
        s.attr('disabled','true');
     }
  });

});
```

You don't *really* need the first part because you can set the initial `disabled` value in your HTML.

Comment: Can you check this version? Because it's not working on click.

Comment: It's working now. I've updated @mashit's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KnBT/26/) if you want to see it in action

Answer (score 1):

Use Following jquery for this.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  // Disable select elements
  $('select').each(function() {
     $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
  });

  // Enable them on click

   $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){

      if($(this).closest("tr").find("td").children("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked"))
       {           
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td").children("select").removeAttr("disabled");
     }
        else
       {
            $(this).closest("tr").find("td").children("select").attr("disabled","disabled");
       }
   });

});
```

See this Link For demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/15/

Comment: Almost there ;-) If I check row one, then row two, row three etc. and then unchek them in the same order 1st, 2nd etc..., only the last one will return dropdown to disabled state. Any ideas?

Comment: As per you say i have update my code and show in jsfiddle link also

Answer (score 0):

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KnBT/3/)

it uses simple javascript function to toggle the dropdown when u click check box.

Comment: If you're dynamically updating your DOM, this won't work because you're relying on the element's inline `onclick()` functionality (which isn't really best practice in my opinion anyway).

Comment: yes true. but it gives flexibility in the sense that you can use it where you want without depending on class attributes.

Comment: You don't have to rely on class attributes at all. You can use any selector you want...